# android variable null pointer

Tags: java, android, variables, null

I think the variable I'm checking is null. 
My on resume method does this:

This method checks for an email on the web and will return -1 if something goes wrong.
I thought this would work.  Now when I ran it 10 times it was working. So I gave it to a friend.  He says it gives him that exception sometimes.

```
///   Ok found it it was in a try catch in the OnCreate() 

tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemz_email);
        tvEmail.setTypeface(TitleFont);

///  and occasionally it didn't even get initialized.
///  I guess ill just init it again in the onResume() just in case.
///  Thanks!


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    tvEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.itemz_email);
        tvEmail.setTypeface(TitleFont);

    if (EMAIL != null) {
        tvEmail.setText("E-mail: " + EMAIL);
    } else {
        tvEmail.setText("E-mail: No Email Available");  //<----==LINE 77
    }
}
```

This is the error my user is getting:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.codalata.craigslistchecker/com.codalata.craigslistchecker.ItemView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2578)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4777)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.codalata.craigslistchecker.ItemView.onResume(ItemView.java:77)<------/**/error/**/
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2568)
```

Should I just check and set it like this?

```
if(EMAIL == null){
    EMAIL = "E-mail: No Email Available"
    tvEmail.setText(EMAIL);
}else {
    tvEmail.setText("E-mail: " + EMAIL);
}
```

Comment: Waht is `tvEmail` and are you sure that it isn't null?

Comment: `tvEmail` must be `null` it wouldn't be your `EMAIL` variable since you aren't even using it on that line. Post how you initialize `tvEmail`

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line.  Debug your program.  Inspect the variables.  What's null?

Comment: Where do you create `tvEmail`?  Can we see that code?

Comment: "I guess ill just init it again in the onResume() just in case." this is crazy. Find out what exception is keeping it from being initialized and fix that or just move the initialization outside of the `try/catch`. There's probably no reason to initialize it twice "just in case"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting a `NullReferenceException` on the line containing `tvEmail.setText(...)`; swapping your conditional blocks to check `EMAIL` for `null` vs. not isn't going to change things, since `EMAIL` isn't getting involved on the line causing the error.

You need to look at `tvEmail`, because *that* is what's being `null` at the time your error occurs.

Comment: tvEmail is a TextView. It should be initialized in onCreate but apparently in some cases it is not being initialized. We need to see that code.

Answer (score 1):

Since we know that the null pointer exception is coming from line 77:

```
tvEmail.setText("E-mail: No Email Available");  //<----==LINE 77
```

We know that the string cannot be null since it is defined in quotes. the method setText can not be null since methods are not objects and can not be null!. That leaves us to the tvEmail object which must be null leading to a null pointer exception. Please ensure that this object was initialized

```
 tvEmail = new TvEmail();//or something similar
```

To make sure that this object is null (to check we are doing the right solution) insert this line of code after

```
 super.onResume();
```

Insert this:

```
if(tvEmail == null) 
    System.out.println("tvEmail is null!!!);
```

If tvEmail is null you may either want to recrate the object or set it equal to something like this:

```
 tvEmail = (TextView)findViewById(id);
```

Answer (score 1):

First check you declared your object in `onCreate` method from Activity or Fragment.etc..
And if you want to check that the object is not null when the `onResume` method is called you it should looks like this. Remember it will be null in else because you said `if` that its not null do that, else its null set email not available but the problem is that in else the variable doesnt have a reference in others words its null, you should also check why your variable its null at that point.

```
if (EMAIL != null) {
    tvEmail.setText("E-mail: " + EMAIL);
} else {
    tvEmail = (TextView)findViewById(id);
    tvEmail.setText("E-mail: No Email Available");
}
```

**Edited**

This is not the best option you should go because you'll create a new object on `onResume` everytime it's called. You should check why the variable is null before `onResume` is called.

Comment: The problem isnt EMAIL being null it is tvEmail.